# Display details page with $routeparams in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm fairly new to anugular and having problems displaying details of an object on another page.

my app.js file:

```
when('/meetings/:id', {
  controller: 'detailController',
  templateUrl: 'views/detail.html'
}).
```

html page:

```
<a href="#/meeting{{$index}}"><div class="item col-md-4" ng-repeat="(key, meeting) in meetings">
```

detailController.js:

```
myApp.controller('detailController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebase', '$routeParams', '$firebaseSimpleLogin', '$location', 'FIREBASE_URL', function(  $scope, $rootScope, $firebase, $routeParams, $firebaseSimpleLogin, $location, FIREBASE_URL) {$scope.whichmeeting = $routeParams.mId; $scope.whichuser = $routeParams.uId;
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + $scope.whichuser + '/meetings/'); var meetingsList = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
    $scope.details = meetingsList[$routeParams.id];
    }]);
```

detail.html:

```
<div class="photo"> <div class="container"><span class="text">{{details.name}}</span><span class="text">{{details.bio}}</span>

    </div>
    </div>
```

don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help! Thank you!!!

Comment: the $index from the <a> refers to what?
I don't understand your code. Can you clean it (tag without end)? Thanks :)

Comment: `<a href="#/meeting{{$index}}">` looks like you're missing a `/`.  Should this match `#/meeting/{{$index}}`?

Comment: is it `/meeting/` or `/meetings/` (note the `s`).  also, @ryanyuyu seems right as well.  overall, this is a series of typos.

Comment: sorry guys. i see that i had a typo in my a tag. it now reads this:
 <a href="#/meetings/{{meeting.name}}">

Comment: it now reads this:
 <a href="#/meetings/{{meeting.name}}">

 Can i take an firebaseArray (which  i can view in the details page as an array of meetings through a variable containing list) and use $routeParams like you would with the http service to get the value of current key:
var meetingsList = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
    $scope.details = meetingsList[$routeParams.id];
    }]); and then display it in the details page like:

<span class="text">{{details.name}}</span>